# How to prevent memory leaks when using dynamic screens?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm creating an app that has screens that present data to the user.
Each `Screen` has its own data and its own layout, so it has a method to return an `int` that represent the layout that is used to inflate it, then this `View` is passed to a function to find the specific views and populate it with data.

The lifecycle goes like this:
MainPresenter:

```
screen.getNextScreen ->
screen.getLayout -> 
view = inflateScreen ->
screen.populateScreen(view) ->
(wait for time elappsed or click) -> repeat
```

Those `Screens` are also needed in `SettingsActivity` to enable\disable them.

So i've created a singleton `ScreenProvider`, it initializes once and then returns the list.

```
public class ScreenProvider {

    private List<Screen> screens;

    private static ScreenProvider instance = new ScreenProvider();

    public static ScreenProvider getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private ScreenProvider() {
        screens = new ArrayList<>();

        screens.add(new Welcome());
        screens.add(new CompoundScreen());
        screens.add(new Times());
        screens.add(new Messages());
        screens.add(new Weekly());
    }

    public List<Screen> getScreenList() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(screens);
    }
}
```

Its seam that when running to long the app crashes or get closed for memory leaks, so i've added leakcanary, and this an example for its report:

```
MainActivity has leaked:
D: * static ScreenProvider.!(instance)!
D: * ↳ ScreenProvider.!(screens)!
D: * ↳ ArrayList.!(array)!
D: * ↳ array Object[].!([0])!
D: * ↳ CompoundScreen.!(disposable)!
D: * ↳ LambdaObserver.!(onNext)!
D: * ↳ -$$Lambda$Screen$67KdQ1jl3VSjSvoRred5JqLGY5Q.!(f$1)!
D: * ↳ AppCompatTextView.mContext
D: * ↳ MainActivity
```

This is just a single example, but almost every screen has such leak.
The LeakCanary report shows that TextView has this: `D: |   mAttachInfo = null` so i assume it is not the problem.
Also every `Screen` has an `onHide()` to clear disposables, that is called when current `Screen` hides and in `MainActivity.onStop()`.

How to fix this leak?
Should i not use a singleton for the screens?
If not, how do i access the screen list from other activities?

** Editing **
Adding some of `Screen` main methods that every screen overrides.

```
public abstract int getLayout();

public boolean shouldShow()

public void populateData(View view)

public void onHide()

public abstract int getScreenIndex();

public boolean shouldCacheView()

public int getDuration()
```

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e

Comment: Is there any reason why you manage all your screens in MainActivity? That doesn't sound good at all. How is it going to end up if you keep adding screens? I'd use a different fragment and presenter from each screen, with its own lifecycle, business logic, etc.

Comment: Is the Screen an interface or wrapper intended to provide a view, or a View by itself? Same question for Welcome and the other ones

Comment: @DavidMiguel Is an `Activity` with a single FrameLayout that attaches a view, removes it and attached another one.
The view is inflated in the MainPresenter. I thought that when a view will be removed it will be garbage collected, except some that i flag as cached.

@FcoP. Its a wrapper. It has a method that get the view and populates its data.

I will edit to add `Screen` code smaple.

Comment: @DavidMiguel I thought `Fragment` has an unnecessary complicated lifecycle.

Comment: If it's a wrapper, are you holding/creating the actual views inside the Screen? Also, can you post the relevant code of MainActivity?

Comment: @SnapDragon You write `every Screen has an onHide() to clear disposables`, but I'd guess you're clearing the disposable in a wrong way, or maybe not keeping them/not adding to a composite disposable. Can you show the subscriptions you make in a `CompoundScreen`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. From what you are saying, and what you are showing, it seems you are keeping instances of some of the generated views into the Singleton. Don't. Every View requires a Context to be created, either by code, or by inflation (which is basically an XML-backed, reflection-based factory method), to access the app and system's resources, and keep a reference to said Context, for as long as they live. In your scenario, that means keeping references to the activity where you generated the view. Usually, regarding views and activities, this is what happens regarding the GC:

```
GC: Hey! Does anybody need this... MainActivity class?
View: I do! I do! I have a reference!
GC: Okay... and besides MainActivity, Does anybody else need this View class?
-Nobody answers-
GC: It does not matter my friend, you are being collected as well. Come with me.
And they both go.
```

In your case:

```
GC: Hey! Does anybody need this... MainActivity class?
View: I do! I do! I have a reference! and MainActivity references me as well.
GC: Okay... and besides MainActivity, Does anybody else need this View class?
ScreenProvider: I do.
GC: Okay, keep moving View, and take MainActivity with you. Let me know when you folks are done so I can collect you.

And thus the leak.
```

In order to pass a view from one activity to another, you would need to remove the reference (the mContext field) to the previous activity. Since there's no API for doing that, you would need to use reflection. And there arises another problem: Every UI piece is a subclass of View. Layouts, Widgets, etc, etc. So either you keep a reference to every piece of your XML file in order to remove the context via reflection, or you traverse the child list of the view, remove the context, and keep going until there are no more child views, at any level. After that, you would have to set the reference to the new activity in the same way. It sounds like a huge hack, because it is, and things are bound to break at some level. A Context after all represents the environment and state within your view exist.

A better solution for your situation is to remove the view references from the singleton, and use it only to keep representations of the state/configuration of a given view. Create a callback backed method (or similar) that inflates the view in background and performs the necessary configurations before returning said view. If you still want to keep a single repository of all the Screens the activity may have, add it to the activity class as a member, so it gets collected alongside the activity.

As a side note, your situation suggests you should use a single activity, and then just swap a "MainScreen" composed of "Screens", or just switch between screens depending on the situation. It would make more sense and would be less risky.

Finally, citing myself: [Remember the first rule of the android fight club](https://twitter.com/FcoPardoBaeza/status/1120018803381944326)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late response, the offices were close.
Can you explain the better solution?